# How to call a function in source from a dll in c

Tags: c++, dll

I have created a DLL in C++ and have successfully been able to use it in another application. What I would like to is to use a function in my application code - NOT THE DLL - and be able to use that function within the DLL.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: you have to add the function to the dll and recompile the dll ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - if you can call functions in your DLL, you can e.g. pass function pointers to it from the hosting application (or another DLL in the same process) and then call those:

```
// DLL side:
typedef void (*CallbackFunc)();
APISTUFF void dllFunction(CallbackFunc f) {
  f();
}

// hosting app side:
void hostFunction() {
    // ...
}

void doPluginStuff() {
  // ... load DLL, resolve dllFunction, etc.
  dllFunction(&hostFunction);
}
```

That is how C-style [plugin APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29) like [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) work.

Comment: THANKS!! That is EXACTLY what I am looking for! I could not find this anywhere. Thanks again.

Comment: So if I wanted to pass a parameter to the function can i do: typedef void(*CallbackFunc)(int pram); void dllFunction(CallbackFunc f){ f(3); } void hostFunction(int param){ ... } ??